# Styling a PHP echo

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to style my PHP `echo` with the class `users` however it does not seem to be applying. I have done some research, but can't workout the difference?

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**PHP**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo '<div class=\"users\">', 'There are ' ,$num_rows, ' registered users', '</div>';
```

**CSS**

```
.users{
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You don't style PHP or echo, you style HTML in general. What does not work because your code looks ok?

Comment: echo '<div class="users">There are ' .$num_rows. ' registered users</div>';

Comment: @Dipak That's totally ok. I don't see a problem at that part at all.

Comment: @Dipak, no I do not know how PHP works

Comment: @Dipak That is perfectly valid with echo

Answer (score 6):

You should not escape the double quotes, that's breaking the HTML.

Change your PHP code to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo '<div class="users">', 'There are ' ,$num_rows, ' registered users', '</div>';
```

The double quotes don't need escaping inside of single quotes.

Comment: Again, you are concatenating the strings using "Comma"

Comment: It's not concatenating strings, it's printing them one next to the other. `echo` can accept multiple parameters, you can check it here: http://codepad.org/5eLD4xkE, and the reference is http://uk1.php.net/echo

Answer (score 3):

change your `echo`

```
echo '<div class="users">There are ' .$num_rows. ' registered users</div>';
```

OR you can use as suggested by @    Sean Doe

```
echo '<div class="users">There are $num_rows registered users</div>';
```

OR You can write simply html and add variable in php

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
<div class="users">There are <?php echo $num_rows; ?> registered users</div>
```

Comment: or simply `echo "<div class='users'>There are $num_rows registered users </div>";`, it looks pretty

Comment: @SeanDoe That depends. This looks prettier to me, because I can see the variables better.

Comment: @DainisAbols I use Netbeans for PHP and it highlights variables in html string. But I agree with you - it depends of your preference

Answer (score 3):

Don't get mad with echo, PHP was born as an HTML preprocessor!

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<div class="users">There are <?php echo $num_rows; ?> registered users</div>
```

Besides that, consider using a template engine [Twig, Mustache, Smarty], and drop `mysql_*` functions in favour of more secure and modern PDO or `mysqli_*` ones.

Answer (score -1):

change your code to this,

```
echo "<div class='users'>"."There are ".$num_rows." registered users"."</div>";
```

php strings are always concat with

```
".$var." not '.$var.'
```